what is the output of this simple recursive function? can you explain in detail?
void test(int start)
{
    for(int i=start; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", start);
        test(i+1);
    }
}

--> test( 0 );

I know the output will be 0-1-0, but I don't understand how the last 0 come from? can anyone help me understand this please?
what if the for loop change to
for(int i=start; i<3; i++)

Thank you in advance

"I know the output will be 0-1-0" - The output depends on what input you give it. What programming language are you using? C?

"what if the for loop change to" Assuming you call test(0) then the output is 0-1-2-1-0-2-0 (but you can find that yourself by making the change and running it). Note; you are printing start not i.

This is an excellent opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

You are printing out start, but seem to be thinking about printing out i
|Variables    | Output|
|-------------|-------|
|start=0, i=0 | 0     |
|start=1, i=1 | 1     |
|start=0, i=1 | 0     |

